# Finding the parametric equations for tangent line to an ellipse at a given point

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

The original question is:
The ellipsoid $4x^2+2y^2+z^2=16$ intersects the plane $y=2$ in an ellipse. Find parametric equations for the tangent line to this ellipse at the point $(1,2,2)$.

I know the slope is $-2$ and the equation of the tangent line at point $(1,2,2)$ is $z-2=-2(x-1), y=2$. The given solution jumped directly from here to the conclusion.

The problem is that I have no idea how to get the directional vector of this tangent line.

Comment: I've always found it helpful to express these intersections in set$-$builder notation: $$\begin{eqnarray*}\{(x,y,z):4x^2+2y^2+z^2=16,y=2\} &=& \{(x,2,z):4x^2+z^2=8\} \\ &=& \Big\{\left(\sqrt{2}\cos(t),2,\sqrt{8}\sin(t)\right):t\in [0,2\pi)\Big\}\end{eqnarray*}$$ Evidently $\vec{r}(t)=\left(\sqrt{2}\cos(t),2,\sqrt{8}\sin(t)\right):t\in[0,2\pi)$ is a parametric representation of your intersection. Can you find equation of tangent line to $\vec{r}(t)$ at $t=\pi/4$?

Comment: Given the ellipse is in the plane $y = 2$, the direction vector will also be in the plane $y = 2$ and so the y-component of the direction vector is simply zero. The equation of the plane that you have written can be simply rewritten as $(z- 2) / - 2 = (x - 1) / 1 = (y-2) / 0 = t$

Answer (score 1):

We write down the equations of the ellipsoid and the plane:
$$
4 x^2 + 2 y^2 + z^2 = 16 \tag{1}
$$
$$
y = 2 \tag{2}
$$

When (1) and (2) intersect,  we find that
$$
4 x^2 + 2 (4) + z^2 = 16 \ \ \mbox{or} \ \
4 x^2 + 8 + z^2 = 16
$$

Thus, the intersection of (1) and (2) is an ellipse:
$$
4 x^2 + z^2 = 8 \tag{3}
$$

We know that the tangent line on the ellipsoid at the point $(1, 2, 2)$ must be an element of the plane $y = 2$.

From the equation of the ellipse, we find the slope at the point $(1, 2)$ using the equation (3):
$$
8 x + 2 z z_x = 0
$$
or
$$
z_x = - {8 x \over 2 z} = - {4 x \over z}
$$

At the point $(1, 2)$,
$$
z_{x} = - {4 \over 2} = -2
$$

Now, the equation of the tangent line to the ellipse (3) at the point (1, 2) is
$$
z - 2 = m (x - 1)   = -2 (x - 1)
$$
since $m = -2$ is the slope.

Simplifying, we get the tangent line as
$$
z = - 2 x + 4 \tag{4}
$$

This shows that the tangent line for the ellipsoid (1) at the point (1, 2, 2) is:
$$
z = - 2 x + 4, \ \ y = 2
$$

We recall that the parametric equations for a line passing through a point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ in the direction of the vector $(l, m, n)$ in the 3-D space is:
$$
{x - x_0 \over l} = {y - y_0 \over m} = {z - z_0 \over n}
$$

It is given that $(x_0, y_0, z_0) = (1, 2, 2)$ and $m = 0$ (Note that the line lies in the plane $y = 2$).

From the equation of the tangent line $z = - 2 x + 4$ obtained in Eq. (4), we get the equation of the tangent line as
$$
{x - 1 \over l} = {y - 2 \over 2} = {z - 2 \over 2} = t
$$

Thus,
$$
x = 1 + l t
$$
$$
y = 2
$$
$$
z = 2 + n t
$$
$$
2 + n t = - 2 ( 1 + l t) + 4  
$$
Simplifying, we get
$$
2 + n t = -2 - 2 l t + 4
$$
or
$$
n t + 2 l t = (n + 2 l) t =  4 - 4 = 0
$$

This gives
$$
n = - 2 l
$$

If we take $l = 1$, then we get $n = -2$.

Thus, we write the parametric equations of the tangent line   as
$$
{x - 1 \over 1} = {y - 2 \over 0} = {z - 2 \over -2} = t
$$
or equivalently
$$
\boxed{x = t + 1, \ \ y = 2, \ \ z = - 2 t + 2}
$$